# IDynamicObject could not be found?

Tags: c#, .net, idynamicobject

When trying to run the sample code here: http://www.nikhilk.net/Live-Search-REST-API.aspx

I get:

> Error 52  The type or namespace name 'IDynamicObject' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    E:\repo\NikhilK-dynamicrest-a93707a\NikhilK-dynamicrest-a93707a\Core\DynamicObject.cs   19  43  DynamicRest

The project is running .net 4 - shouldn't this be a part of the standard imports? am i missing something? What do i need to do to make this work?

Comment: Did you ever get the DynamicRest code working in .NET 4.0 RTM?  It seems that this is not the only compilation error.  If not, did you find a different solution to deserialising JSON to a `dynamic`?

Comment: nah - sorry dude - never got it working - it's a shame. there is RestSharp which IMO does a better job anyway - you should check that out - I did a short blog post on it: http://iwayneo.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-restsharp-to-access-itunes-search.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that the interface has been renamed to `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` (the new name is supposed to be more intuitive, I guess...):

- See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.idynamicmetaobjectprovider.aspx) for the type

Comment: fekin jokers! whay do they do that?!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the github repository [here](https://github.com/NikhilK/dynamicrest) for updated code.